# windows.resize() is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi guys i am using d3 charts in my html body tag.  i want to resize the d3 chart width and height automatically when the browser window is resized.

here i have attached my code
d3.min.js `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` u can get this js code from internet
,

`d3-legend .js`

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var helper = require('./legend');

module.exports = function(){

  var scale = d3.scale.linear(),
    shape = "rect",
    shapeWidth = 15,
    shapeHeight = 15,
    shapeRadius = 10,
    shapePadding = 2,
    cells = [5],
    labels = [],
    useClass = false,
    labelFormat = d3.format(".01f"),
    labelOffset = 10,
    labelAlign = "middle",
    labelDelimiter = "to",
    orient = "vertical",
    path,
    legendDispatcher = d3.dispatch("cellover", "cellout", "cellclick");

    function legend(svg){

      var type = helper.d3_calcType(scale, cells, labels, labelFormat, labelDelimiter);

      var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell").data(type.data),
        cellEnter = cell.enter().append("g", ".cell").attr("class", "cell").style("opacity", 1e-6);
        shapeEnter = cellEnter.append(shape).attr("class", "swatch"),
        shapes = cell.select("g.cell " + shape);

      //add event handlers
      helper.d3_addEvents(cellEnter, legendDispatcher);

      cell.exit().transition().style("opacity", 0).remove();

      helper.d3_drawShapes(shape, shapes, shapeHeight, shapeWidth, shapeRadius, path);

      helper.d3_addText(svg, cellEnter, type.labels)

      // sets placement
      var text = cell.select("text"),
        shapeSize = shapes[0].map( function(d){ return d.getBBox(); });

      //sets scale
      //everything is fill except for line which is stroke,
      if (!useClass){
        if (shape == "line"){
          shapes.style("stroke", type.feature);
        } else {
          shapes.style("fill", type.feature);
        }
      } else {
        shapes.attr("class", function(d){ return "swatch " + type.feature(d); });
      }

      var cellTrans,
      textTrans,
      textAlign = (labelAlign == "start") ? 0 : (labelAlign == "middle") ? 0.5 : 1;

      //positions cells and text
      if (orient === "vertical"){
        cellTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(0, " + (i * (shapeSize[i].height + shapePadding)) + ")"; };
        textTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (shapeSize[i].width + shapeSize[i].x +
          labelOffset) + "," + (shapeSize[i].y + shapeSize[i].height/2 + 5) + ")"; };

      } else if (orient === "horizontal"){
        cellTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (i * (shapeSize[i].width + shapePadding)) + ",0)"; }
        textTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (shapeSize[i].width*textAlign  + shapeSize[i].x) +
          "," + (shapeSize[i].height + shapeSize[i].y + labelOffset + 8) + ")"; };
      }

      helper.d3_placement(orient, cell, cellTrans, text, textTrans, labelAlign);
      cell.transition().style("opacity", 1);

    }



  legend.scale = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    scale = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.cells = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_.length > 1 || _ >= 2 ){
      cells = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shape = function(_, d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_ == "rect" || _ == "circle" || _ == "line" || (_ == "path" && (typeof d === 'string')) ){
      shape = _;
      path = d;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapeWidth = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapeWidth = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapeHeight = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapeHeight = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapeRadius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapeRadius = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapePadding = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapePadding = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labels = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labels = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelAlign = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_ == "start" || _ == "end" || _ == "middle") {
      labelAlign = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelFormat = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelOffset = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelOffset = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelDelimiter = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelDelimiter = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.useClass = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_ === true || _ === false){
      useClass = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.orient = function(_){
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    _ = _.toLowerCase();
    if (_ == "horizontal" || _ == "vertical") {
      orient = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  d3.rebind(legend, legendDispatcher, "on");

  return legend;

};


},{"./legend":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = {

d3_identity: function (d) {
  return d;
},

d3_mergeLabels: function (gen, labels) {

    if(labels.length === 0) return gen;

    gen = (gen) ? gen : [];

    var i = labels.length;
    for (; i < gen.length; i++) {
      labels.push(gen[i]);
    }
    return labels;
  },

d3_linearLegend: function (scale, cells, labelFormat) {
  var data = [];

  if (cells.length > 1){
    data = cells;

  } else {
    var domain = scale.domain(),
    increment = (domain[domain.length - 1] - domain[0])/(cells - 1),
    i = 0;

    for (; i < cells; i++){
      data.push(labelFormat(domain[0] + i*increment));
    }
  }

  return {data: data,
          labels: data,
          feature: function(d){ return scale(d); }};
},

d3_quantLegend: function (scale, labelFormat, labelDelimiter) {
  var labels = scale.range().map(function(d){
    var invert = scale.invertExtent(d),
    a = labelFormat(invert[0]),
    b = labelFormat(invert[1]);

    // if (( (a) && (a.isNan()) && b){
    //   console.log("in initial statement")
      return labelFormat(invert[0]) + " " + labelDelimiter + " " + labelFormat(invert[1]);
    // } else if (a || b) {
    //   console.log('in else statement')
    //   return (a) ? a : b;
    // }

  });

  return {data: scale.range(),
          labels: labels,
          feature: this.d3_identity
        };
},

d3_ordinalLegend: function (scale) {
  return {data: scale.domain(),
          labels: scale.domain(),
          feature: function(d){ return scale(d); }};
},

d3_drawShapes: function (shape, shapes, shapeHeight, shapeWidth, shapeRadius, path) {
  if (shape === "rect"){
      shapes.attr("height", shapeHeight).attr("width", shapeWidth);

  } else if (shape === "circle") {
      shapes.attr("r", shapeRadius)//.attr("cx", shapeRadius).attr("cy", shapeRadius);

  } else if (shape === "line") {
      shapes.attr("x1", 0).attr("x2", shapeWidth).attr("y1", 0).attr("y2", 0);

  } else if (shape === "path") {
    shapes.attr("d", path);
  }
},

d3_addText: function (svg, enter, labels){
  enter.append("text").attr("class", "label");
  svg.selectAll("g.cell text").data(labels).text(this.d3_identity);
},

d3_calcType: function (scale, cells, labels, labelFormat, labelDelimiter){
  var type = scale.ticks ?
          this.d3_linearLegend(scale, cells, labelFormat) : scale.invertExtent ?
          this.d3_quantLegend(scale, labelFormat, labelDelimiter) : this.d3_ordinalLegend(scale);

  type.labels = this.d3_mergeLabels(type.labels, labels);

  return type;
},

d3_placement: function (orient, cell, cellTrans, text, textTrans, labelAlign) {
  cell.attr("transform", cellTrans);
  text.attr("transform", textTrans);
  if (orient === "horizontal"){
    text.style("text-anchor", labelAlign);
  }
},

d3_addEvents: function(cells, dispatcher){
  var _ = this;

    cells.on("mouseover.legend", function (d) { _.d3_cellOver(dispatcher, d, this); })
        .on("mouseout.legend", function (d) { _.d3_cellOut(dispatcher, d, this); })
        .on("click.legend", function (d) { _.d3_cellClick(dispatcher, d, this); });
},

d3_cellOver: function(cellDispatcher, d, obj){
  cellDispatcher.cellover.call(obj, d);
},

d3_cellOut: function(cellDispatcher, d, obj){
  cellDispatcher.cellout.call(obj, d);
},

d3_cellClick: function(cellDispatcher, d, obj){
  cellDispatcher.cellclick.call(obj, d);
}

}

},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
var helper = require('./legend');

module.exports =  function(){

  var scale = d3.scale.linear(),
    shape = "rect",
    shapeWidth = 15,
    shapePadding = 2,
    cells = [5],
    labels = [],
    useStroke = false,
    labelFormat = d3.format(".01f"),
    labelOffset = 10,
    labelAlign = "middle",
    labelDelimiter = "to",
    orient = "vertical",
    path,
    legendDispatcher = d3.dispatch("cellover", "cellout", "cellclick");

    function legend(svg){

      var type = helper.d3_calcType(scale, cells, labels, labelFormat, labelDelimiter);

      var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell").data(type.data),
        cellEnter = cell.enter().append("g", ".cell").attr("class", "cell").style("opacity", 1e-6);
        shapeEnter = cellEnter.append(shape).attr("class", "swatch"),
        shapes = cell.select("g.cell " + shape);

      //add event handlers
      helper.d3_addEvents(cellEnter, legendDispatcher);

      cell.exit().transition().style("opacity", 0).remove();

      //creates shape
      if (shape === "line"){
        helper.d3_drawShapes(shape, shapes, 0, shapeWidth);
        shapes.attr("stroke-width", type.feature);
      } else {
        helper.d3_drawShapes(shape, shapes, type.feature, type.feature, type.feature, path);
      }

      helper.d3_addText(svg, cellEnter, type.labels)

      //sets placement
      var text = cell.select("text"),
        shapeSize = shapes[0].map(
          function(d, i){
            var bbox = d.getBBox()
            var stroke = scale(type.data[i]);

            if (shape === "line" && orient === "horizontal") {
              bbox.height = bbox.height + stroke;
            } else if (shape === "line" && orient === "vertical"){
              bbox.width = bbox.width;
            }

            return bbox;
        });

      var maxH = d3.max(shapeSize, function(d){ return d.height + d.y; }),
      maxW = d3.max(shapeSize, function(d){ return d.width + d.x; });

      var cellTrans,
      textTrans,
      textAlign = (labelAlign == "start") ? 0 : (labelAlign == "middle") ? 0.5 : 1;

      //positions cells and text
      if (orient === "vertical"){

        cellTrans = function(d,i) {
            var height = d3.sum(shapeSize.slice(0, i + 1 ), function(d){ return d.height; });
            return "translate(0, " + (height + i*shapePadding) + ")"; };

        textTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (maxW + labelOffset) + "," +
          (shapeSize[i].y + shapeSize[i].height/2 + 5) + ")"; };

      } else if (orient === "horizontal"){
        cellTrans = function(d,i) {
            var width = d3.sum(shapeSize.slice(0, i + 1 ), function(d){ return d.width; });
            return "translate(" + (width + i*shapePadding) + ",0)"; };

        textTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (shapeSize[i].width*textAlign  + shapeSize[i].x) + "," +
              (maxH + labelOffset ) + ")"; };
      }

      helper.d3_placement(orient, cell, cellTrans, text, textTrans, labelAlign);
      cell.transition().style("opacity", 1);

    }



  legend.scale = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    scale = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.cells = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_.length > 1 || _ >= 2 ){
      cells = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };


  legend.shape = function(_, d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_ == "rect" || _ == "circle" || _ == "line" ){
      shape = _;
      path = d;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapeWidth = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapeWidth = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapePadding = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapePadding = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labels = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labels = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelAlign = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_ == "start" || _ == "end" || _ == "middle") {
      labelAlign = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelFormat = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelOffset = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelOffset = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelDelimiter = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelDelimiter = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.orient = function(_){
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    _ = _.toLowerCase();
    if (_ == "horizontal" || _ == "vertical") {
      orient = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  d3.rebind(legend, legendDispatcher, "on");

  return legend;

};


},{"./legend":2}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
var helper = require('./legend');

module.exports = function(){

  var scale = d3.scale.linear(),
    shape = "path",
    shapeWidth = 15,
    shapeHeight = 15,
    shapeRadius = 10,
    shapePadding = 5,
    cells = [5],
    labels = [],
    useClass = false,
    labelFormat = d3.format(".01f"),
    labelAlign = "middle",
    labelOffset = 10,
    labelDelimiter = "to",
    orient = "vertical",
    legendDispatcher = d3.dispatch("cellover", "cellout", "cellclick");

    function legend(svg){

      var type = helper.d3_calcType(scale, cells, labels, labelFormat, labelDelimiter);

      var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell").data(type.data),
        cellEnter = cell.enter().append("g", ".cell").attr("class", "cell").style("opacity", 1e-6);
        shapeEnter = cellEnter.append(shape).attr("class", "swatch"),
        shapes = cell.select("g.cell " + shape);

      //add event handlers
      helper.d3_addEvents(cellEnter, legendDispatcher);

      //remove old shapes
      cell.exit().transition().style("opacity", 0).remove();

      helper.d3_drawShapes(shape, shapes, shapeHeight, shapeWidth, shapeRadius, type.feature);
      helper.d3_addText(svg, cellEnter, type.labels)

      // sets placement
      var text = cell.select("text"),
        shapeSize = shapes[0].map( function(d){ return d.getBBox(); });

      var maxH = d3.max(shapeSize, function(d){ return d.height; }),
      maxW = d3.max(shapeSize, function(d){ return d.width; });

      var cellTrans,
      textTrans,
      textAlign = (labelAlign == "start") ? 0 : (labelAlign == "middle") ? 0.5 : 1;

      //positions cells and text
      if (orient === "vertical"){
        cellTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(0, " + (i * (maxH + shapePadding)) + ")"; };
        textTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (maxW + labelOffset) + "," +
              (shapeSize[i].y + shapeSize[i].height/2 + 5) + ")"; };

      } else if (orient === "horizontal"){
        cellTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (i * (maxW + shapePadding)) + ",0)"; };
        textTrans = function(d,i) { return "translate(" + (shapeSize[i].width*textAlign  + shapeSize[i].x) + "," +
              (maxH + labelOffset ) + ")"; };
      }

      helper.d3_placement(orient, cell, cellTrans, text, textTrans, labelAlign);
      cell.transition().style("opacity", 1);

    }


  legend.scale = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    scale = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.cells = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_.length > 1 || _ >= 2 ){
      cells = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.shapePadding = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    shapePadding = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labels = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labels = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelAlign = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    if (_ == "start" || _ == "end" || _ == "middle") {
      labelAlign = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelFormat = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelOffset = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelOffset = +_;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.labelDelimiter = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    labelDelimiter = _;
    return legend;
  };

  legend.orient = function(_){
    if (!arguments.length) return legend;
    _ = _.toLowerCase();
    if (_ == "horizontal" || _ == "vertical") {
      orient = _;
    }
    return legend;
  };

  d3.rebind(legend, legendDispatcher, "on");

  return legend;

};


},{"./legend":2}],5:[function(require,module,exports){
d3.legend = {
  color: require('./color'),
  size: require('./size'),
  symbol: require('./symbol')
};
},{"./color":1,"./size":3,"./symbol":4}]},{},[5]);



   legend code ending here
```

i have use the following code

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Example</title>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3-legend.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    body { font: 12px Arial;}

 path { 
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
 }
      .axis text {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }
      .axis .label {
        font-size: 20pt;
      }

      .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .color-legend text {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }

rect:hover {
    fill: #3EBCE6;
   }
.toolTip {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
    color: black;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


    <script>


      var outerWidth = window.innerWidth-30;
      var outerHeight = window.innerHeight-80;
      var margin = { left: 50, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40 };

      var barPadding = 0.2;

      var xColumn = "Building";
      var yColumn = "Total";
      var colorColumn = "Type";
      var layerColumn = colorColumn;


      var innerWidth  = outerWidth- margin.left - margin.right;
      var innerHeight = outerHeight- margin.top  - margin.bottom;

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width",  outerWidth)
        .attr("height", outerHeight+50);
      var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");
      var xAxisG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
      var yAxisG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");
      var colorLegendG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "color-legend")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(outerWidth-200)+", 0)");


    debugger;
      var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth-150], barPadding);
      var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);
      var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
        .outerTickSize(0);
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
        .ticks(7)
        .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
        .outerTickSize(0);

      var colorLegend = d3.legend.color()
        .scale(colorScale)
        .shapePadding(2)
        .shapeWidth(15)
        .shapeHeight(15)
        .labelOffset(4);

      function render(data){

        var nested = d3.nest()
          .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
          .entries(data)

        var stack = d3.layout.stack()
          .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
          .values(function (d){ return d.values; });

        var layers = stack(nested);





//tool tip for div class
var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

        xScale.domain(layers[0].values.map(function (d){
          return d[xColumn];
        }));

        yScale.domain([
          0,
          d3.max(layers, function (layer){
            return d3.max(layer.values, function (d){
              return d.y;
            });
          })
        ]);

        colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
          return layer.key;
        }));

        xAxisG.call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.5em")
            .attr("dy", "-.0em")

            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-45)" 
                });
        yAxisG.call(yAxis);

        var layers = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
        layers.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
        layers.exit().remove();
        layers.style("fill", function (d){
          return colorScale(d.key);
        });

        var bars = layers.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
          return d.values;
        });
        var barWidth = xScale.rangeBand() / colorScale.domain().length;
        bars.enter()
  .append("rect")
        bars.exit().remove();
        bars

          .attr("x", function (d, i, j){
            return xScale(d[xColumn]) + barWidth * j;
          })

          .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y); })
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); })


    //toolTip mouse hover on bar
    bars.on("mousemove", function(d){
        divTooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
        divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
        divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
        var x = d3.event.pageX,
  y = d3.event.pageY
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
        l = elements.length
        l = l-1
        elementData = function(d){return d}
        divTooltip.html((d.Building)+"<br>"+"Type:"+d.Type+"<br>"+"Small:"+d.Small+"<br>"+"Medium:"+d.Medium+"<br>"+"Large:"+d.Large+"<br>"+"Total:"+d.Total+"<br>");
    })
 //tooltip mouse release on bar
 bars.on("mouseout", function(d){
        divTooltip.style("display", "none");
    })




 //legend
   .text(function(d) {
         return d.VALUE;
         });
        colorLegendG.call(colorLegend);
     //resize                   
                    window.onresize = function () {
                    debugger;
                    // new width
                    var width = window.innerWidth;
                    svg.attr("width", width);

                    // new x scale
                    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width], 0.2);
                    // update x axis
                   xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                      .scale(xScale)
                                      .orient("bottom")
                                      .ticks(10);
                    svg.select(".x.axis")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(5000)
                        .call(xAxis);
                    // update bars

                }
      }

      function type(d){

        d.Total = +d.Total;
        return d;
      }

      d3.csv("D3.csv", type, render);




// Define the div for the tooltip


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here i have add my csv file

```
Building,Type,Small,Medium,Large,Total
Building1,Food,18,38,40,96
Building1,Medicine,24,38,24,86
Building2,Food,31,24,40,95
Building2,Medicine,17,38,22,77
Building3,Food,24,24,22,70
Building3,Medicine,27,38,40,105
Building4,Food,23,38,24,85
Building4,Medicine,20,38,22,80
Building5,Food,17,24,40,81
Building5,Medicine,40,38,22,100
Building6,Food,18,38,40,96
Building6,Medicine,24,38,24,86
Building7,Food,31,24,40,95
Building7,Medicine,17,38,22,77
Building8,Food,24,24,22,70
Building8,Medicine,27,38,40,105
```

but this is not working for me. when i press refresh button then only it will resize can anyone solve my issue

Comment: Have you added the onresize property on `<body>` like so: `<body onresize="myFunction()">`?

Comment: yes but it is not resized automatically

Comment: can you show your code.

Comment: i have add my body tag code in my quesiton. can you see my code

Comment: can you put w and h as global variables and access them everywhere else? or you can initialize a function named init() that initialize everything in d3 and recall it when resize is triggered

Comment: i am not using any global variable .where should i use init function in my d3 can you tell me @z0r0

Comment: put all your js code in a function named init() and on window resize call it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to trigger the resize of chart

```
        window.onresize = function(){ //logic to resize the chart }
```

or

```
        window.onresize = myFunction;
```

As requested I have modified your code for chart. Here is the updated html file:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Example</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="d3-legend.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 12px Arial;
    }

    path {
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill: none;
    }

    .axis text {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 12pt;
    }

    .axis .label {
      font-size: 20pt;
    }

    .axis path, .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .color-legend text {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 12pt;
    }

    rect:hover {
      fill: #3EBCE6;
    }

    .toolTip {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
      border: 0 none;
      border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
      box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
      color: black;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<script>

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
  var margin = {left: 50, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40};

  var barPadding = 0.2;

  var xColumn = "Building";
  var yColumn = "Total";
  var colorColumn = "Type";
  var xAxisShift = 150;
  var layerColumn, xScale, yScale, xAxisG, yAxisG, colorLegendG, xAxis, yAxis, g;
  var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();
  var colorLegend = d3.legend.color()
    .scale(colorScale)
    .shapePadding(2)
    .shapeWidth(15)
    .shapeHeight(15)
    .labelOffset(4);


  function recalculateDimensions() {
    var outerWidth = window.innerWidth - 30;
  var outerHeight = window.innerHeight - 80;
  layerColumn = colorColumn;


  var innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    svg.attr("width", outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight + 50);
  g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");
  xAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
  yAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");
  colorLegendG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "color-legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (outerWidth - 200) + ", 0)");


  xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth - xAxisShift], barPadding);
  yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);

  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
    .ticks(7)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
    .outerTickSize(0);


  }

  recalculateDimensions();

  function render(data) {

    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d) {
        return d[layerColumn];
      })
      .entries(data)

    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .y(function (d) {
        return d[yColumn];
      })
      .values(function (d) {
        return d.values;
      });

    var layers = stack(nested);


//tool tip for div class
    var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    xScale.domain(layers[0].values.map(function (d) {
      return d[xColumn];
    }));

    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(layers, function (layer) {
        return d3.max(layer.values, function (d) {
          return d.y;
        });
      })
    ]);

    colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer) {
      return layer.key;
    }));

    xAxisG.call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.5em")
      .attr("dy", "-.0em")

      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-45)"
      });
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    var layers = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
    layers.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
    layers.exit().remove();
    layers.style("fill", function (d) {
      return colorScale(d.key);
    });

    var bars = layers.selectAll("rect").data(function (d) {
      return d.values;
    });
    var barWidth = xScale.rangeBand() / colorScale.domain().length;
    bars.enter()
      .append("rect")
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars

      .attr("x", function (d, i, j) {
        return xScale(d[xColumn]) + barWidth * j;
      })

      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
      })
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .attr("height", function (d) {
        return innerHeight - yScale(d.y) - xAxisShift;
      })


    //toolTip mouse hover on bar
    bars.on("mousemove", function (d) {
      divTooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
      divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 25 + "px");
      divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
      var x = d3.event.pageX,
        y = d3.event.pageY
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
      l = elements.length
      l = l - 1
      elementData = function (d) {
        return d
      }
      divTooltip.html((d.Building) + "<br>" + "Type:" + d.Type + "<br>" + "Small:" + d.Small + "<br>" + "Medium:" + d.Medium + "<br>" + "Large:" + d.Large + "<br>" + "Total:" + d.Total + "<br>");
    })
    //tooltip mouse release on bar
    bars.on("mouseout", function (d) {
      divTooltip.style("display", "none");
    })




    //legend
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.VALUE;
      });
    colorLegendG.call(colorLegend);
  }

  function type(d) {

    d.Total = +d.Total;
    return d;
  }

  d3.csv("D3.csv", type, function(data){
    chartData = data;
    render(chartData);
  });


  // Define the div for the tooltip
window.onresize = function () {
      d3.select('svg>g').remove();
      recalculateDimensions();
        render(chartData);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The preferred solution would be to use svg like below, which would make it responsive out-of-the-box

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 525 365" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"></svg>
```

Comment: already I tried this one. this is also not resize automatically. see my code before legend that is not working for me@ abhishek

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR Inside the onresize function, you need to redraw the chart. But in your code your are setting the width of svg. This alone won't solve the problem. Try redraw the chart inside onresize function.

Comment: @Adhishek:do i have to paste all my code in to  onresize funtion(). for automatically resize. Can you correct my onresize funtion?

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR I have updated my answered with your code corrected to work on resize. Hope thos solves the problem.

Comment: Hi Abhi:here it is not visible anything. where should i add that svg tag in code. have you run this code in your sys.  If yes, send that code to my mailid : vinothkumarsm92@gmail.com.

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR Yes I have tested and shared the code to your mailid.

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR can you please confirm mailid mentioned above is correct ? The mail sent to was failed to deliver. Also I have updated the answer with full html. Copy entire code of html and test it once.

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR Did you get a chance to check the solution/answer ? If yes, does it solved your problem ?

Comment: :@Abhi :yes above mail id is correct "vinothkumarsm92@gmail.com" or can you tell me your mail ID : i will send a mail to you.

Comment: :@Abhi Thank you for your help.Y-axis scale is only responsive  and but the y-axis bars is not responsive, and all the bars are in wrong positon EX:"Building 1, Type: food, total :93 but the bar is in above 100"bar values are not placed correctly  when the window is resized max. i have upload the photo in my question just see that.

Comment: :@ABHI: resize of width is looking gud but the height is not working correctly.

Comment: :@Abhi:.attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.y) -xAxisShift;
      })                                                                                                                       if i remove xAxusShift in above code this working good. but the bar is start from end of the browser. can you see this

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR my mail id : abhiisheek@hotmail.com

Comment: :@Abhi : i have send a mail to you kindly check the 3rd mail and see my demo.

Answer (score 0):

A function must return something to work. `myFunction()` only catch windows inner height and width but doesn't return it.
replace this with your function:

```
function myFunction() {
     var m = new Array();
     m['w'] = window.outerWidth;
     m['h'] = window.outerHeight;
     return m;

}
```

then get values like this:

```
var m = myFunction();
currentWidth = m['w'];
currentHeight = m['h'];
```

**If this is not what you looking for please let me know**

Comment: try correcting the function and add it to your question before downvoters come

Comment: is there any mistakes in my js funtion.. @sagar

Comment: @Mahdi azarm: i have updated my question. I want to resize the chart automatically when the browser is resized.